Pass textbox entry to XLookup formula
I have a variable from a textbox. When I use it inside the xlookup formula it can't find the item.
LotNum is the name of the text box, it can be numbers and letters.
Public ICN as Variant

ICN = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(LotNum.Value, Sheets(xlRangeFound).Range("H:H"), Sheets(xlRangeFound).Range("U:U"))

If I type the number I'm looking for in the formula without quotes, it works:
ICN = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(1444825, Sheets(xlRangeFound).Range("H:H"), Sheets(xlRangeFound).Range("U:U"))

The LotNum.Value is the same as 1444825.
ICN should return a specific value which is C380012.

Your variable from a textbox is likely a string, not numeric.

I know that. Anything I can do about that or something more specific?

Use CLng likely to cast to numeric.

Thanks! I had to implement an "IF" statement to either convert it to string or long depending on the input, as some materials I have the lot numbers are strings and some others are only numbers. Thanks for the help, really appreciate it!

Thanks for the suggestion BigBen
I created a new variable called "LotNumber" as Variant, and because some of the variables are only numbers and for some other string, I created an "IF" statement as follows:
   Dim LotNumber As Variant


On Error Resume Next
    If MatType = 1 Then
        LotNumber = CStr(LotNum.Value)
    Else
        LotNumber = CLng(LotNum.Value)
    End If

    ICN = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(LotNumber, Sheets(xlRangeFound).Range("H:H"), Sheets(xlRangeFound).Range("U:U"))
On Error GoTo 0

This converted whatever I input inside the LotNum Textbox to the correct type for evaluation.

If your Col H has a mix of numeric and non-numeric values then it might be a good idea to store all the values as Text, so you can have a single reliable method for matching values.
